# React Semantic UI cannot submit a form inside Modal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to make a modal where people can submit a form using React semantic UI. Somehow the submit button does not work and the answers are not submitted to Google Form even though I added `action={GOOGLE Form URL}`. Here is the part of the code and I hope someone can figure out why. Click event on the button works because it logs something if I add `console.log()`

```
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ENDPOINT = "http~~~"

return (
    <Modal open={isModalOpen} as={Form}>
      <Modal.Header>
        この製品の改善のためにアンケート調査のご協力をお願いします。
      </Modal.Header>
      {/* <Header
        icon="pencil"
        content="この製品の改善のためにアンケート調査のご協力をお願いします。"
        as="h2"
      /> */}
      <Modal.Content>
        <Form action={GOOGLE_FORM_ENDPOINT}>
          <Form.Field>
            <label htmlFor="game">他にプレイしたいゲームはありますか？</label>
            <input
              id="game"
              name="entry.1294001289"
              placeholder="ポーカー、人狼、人生ゲーム・・・"
              required
            ></input>
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <label htmlFor="price">
              今遊んだゲームに買い切りでいくら払いますか？（10円単位でお願いします。）
            </label>
            <input
              id="price"
              type="number"
              name="entry.1184266257"
              placeholder="5000"
              min="0"
              step="10"
              required
            />
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <label htmlFor="request">
              その他、何かご要望やご意見があればお願いします。
            </label>
            <textarea id="request" name="entry.656434793"></textarea>
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Button
            content="submit"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault()
              setIsModalOpen(false)
              app?.endGameRequest()
            }}
          ></Form.Button>
        </Form>
      </Modal.Content>
    </Modal>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `e.preventDefault()` you prevent from the browser to do what should do - submit the `form`.

You have 2 options to submit the form:

1. Remove `e.preventDefault()` and let the browser to do its magic. Drawback: the browser will redirect the user to the action URL. This is probably not the experience you want for your users. Which leads to the second option.
2. Prevent the form submission with `e.preventDefault()` but submit the `form` using ajax - e.g. [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).